# How to create a daterange in PostgreSQL using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, postgresql-9.2, range-types

I'm using Rails 3.2.7 and Postgres 9.2 trying to create a daterange

Here's how I'm creating it

```
schedule_block              = ScheduleBlock.new
schedule_block.date_range   = [Date.new, Date.new]
schedule_block.save
```

And here's the resulting query and the error:

```
INSERT INTO "schedule_blocks" ("date_range") VALUES ($1) RETURNING "id"  [["date_range", [Mon, 01 Jan -4712, Mon, 01 Jan -4712]]]
PG::Error: ERROR:  malformed range literal: "---
- -4712-01-01
- -4712-01-01
"
DETAIL:  Missing left parenthesis or bracket.
: INSERT INTO "schedule_blocks" ("date_range") VALUES ($1) RETURNING "id"
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 496ms
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Great question, just came to ask exactly this. What did you use in your migration?

Comment: add_column :table_name, :col_name, :daterange

Comment: [psql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/psql) is the command line client of PostgreSQL and has its own tag. Don't confuse it with PostgreSQL (or Postgres for short). I fixed it.

Comment: Isn't the problem that rails has no idea what a daterange is? Much in the same as it doesn't know what an interval is. As such wouldn't you need to convert to a string approiately? Looking at what the error is, it looks like it's just dumping your array of dates into sql... which is obviously invalid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

will be available in rails 4 if this pull request will be merged - https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/7345

Comment: To save the hassle of digging in to see if the pull request for ranges was merged, it was. You can read about using ranges (and some of the gotchas) at http://www.simontaranto.com/2013/12/31/using-postgresql-s-tsrange-range-type-with-rails.html